# Stage Table in MySQL/ or Pentaho Spoon

Tags: mysql, pentaho

What is Stage Table and how can I create one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A staging table is merely a table which is used as a middle man in your ETL Process.  You may for example copy all your raw data into a staging table, and then process it.

You dont always need one. So asking how can I create one is the wrong question.

What is your data scenario?

Finally; A staging table is no different to any other table. It's stored in a db. Sometimes people have a staging database for those tables, but thats just a normal database. There's no special technology or objects here - just normal database functionality.